# fullpage.js change scroll direction on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, fullpage.js

I am using [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) to create a wp site, I wonder if it is possible change the scroll direction when the user gets to a certain page.

To explain better, let's use this this example:
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/navigationV.html

Is it possible for the scroll direction to change to horizontal when you visit the [second slide](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/navigationV.html#secondPage)?

So instead of clicking on the arrows to navigate horizontally, I want the mouse wheel to scroll horizontally.

Is this possible with fullpage.js or do I have to change to another script?

Comment: I made some edits to improve the clarity of your question. If I got anything wrong, please correct it or revert the edit.

Comment: This is now possible through the fullpage.js extension [Scroll Horizontally](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/continuousHorizontal.html).

Answer (score 2):

Okay, here's the basic method:

1. When you get to a page that needs horizontally scrolled, add a `mousewheel` listener that:
2. Turns scroll events into left or right slide changes and
3. Prevents the default for the mousewheel unless:

   - Last slide and scroll down *or*
   - First slide and scroll up
4. Turn off the listener when you enter another slide.

There is also some code to prevent things from happening while slides are loading.

```
var currentSlide = 0;
var loaded = false;
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    navigation: true,
    navigationTooltips: ['First section', 'Second section', 'Third section'],
    sectionsColor: ['#f1c40f', '#e67e22', '#c0392b'],
    loopHorizontal: false,
    afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index){
        loaded = true;
    },
    afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
        currentSlide = slideIndex;
        loaded = true;
    },
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
        loaded = false;
        if (nextIndex == 2) {
            $('#fullpage').on("mousewheel",function(e){
                if(loaded){
                    loaded = false;
                    var delta = e.originalEvent.deltaY;
                    console.log(delta);

                    if(delta>0){ //down
                        if(currentSlide===2){//if last slide
                            $('#fullpage').off("mousewheel");
                        }else{
                            $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
                            e.preventDefault();
                            e.stopPropagation();
                        }
                    }else{ //up
                        if(currentSlide===0){//if first slide
                            $('#fullpage').off("mousewheel");
                        }else{
                            $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideLeft();
                            e.preventDefault();
                            e.stopPropagation();
                        }
                    }
                }else{ //slide still loading, don't scroll
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/4o3qLr8j/7/)

This works on Chrome. I'm not sure how cross browser the `e.originalEvent.deltaY` bit is. You can replace the mousewheel handler with [this plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel) to make it properly cross platform.

---

Here's a [JSFiddle with jquery.mousewheel](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/4o3qLr8j/8/) for a fully cross platform solution.

Comment: I was on it too ^^, clear and working, great job dude. Maybe you should do it more dynamic, like adding `data-direction=horizontal` to determine which section has to be scrolled horizontally, and use `$(".section"+currentSection+" .slide").length` to get max value, but this is already awsome ;)

Comment: @EdenSource Yeah, if I was using this in a project I would. But this demonstrates the solution without giving the complete code. That way anyone using it actually has to understand it to make it work in their project.

Comment: @mattia Yes, like the last paragraph said, you need to use the mousewheel plugin to make it work on all browsers. **I've added an example JSFiddle with it added**, but this is the kind of thing you should be attempting to do on your own.

Comment: @slicedtoad i am sorry, i didn't read the last paragraph, I was focus on the code. I try now, sorry again and thanks again